# how can I once I select a field the other fields have values?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

What I want is once I choose the first field the fields related to this choice have their values

[image]

```html
    nameTest = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='medical.lab.patient',
        required=True,
    )
```

nameTest is an object how can I access the fields related to this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options here (i've changed `nameTest` to `my_many2one_id` in my examples!):

1. use onchange behaviour

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    my_many2one_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='medical.lab.patient',
        required=True
    )
    my_field1 = fields.Boolean(string="My Field1")
    my_field2 = fields.Char(string="My Field2")

    @api.onchange('my_many2one_id')
    def onchange_my_many2one_id(self):
        self.my_field1 = self.my_many2one_id.my_field1
        self.my_field2 = self.my_many2one_id.my_field2
```

2. use related fields

```py
    my_field3 = fields.Boolean(
        string="My Field3", related="my_many2one_id.my_other_field3")
    my_field4 = fields.Char(
        string="My Field4", related="my_many2one_id.my_other_field4")
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need is related field :

let say there is `model.one`

```py
 _name = 'model.one'

 field_1 = fields.Char(..)
 field_2 = fields.Date(..)
```

and model `model.two` that have one2many field to `model.one`

```py
_name = 'model.two'

 many2one_field = fields.Many2one(co_model='model.one', ....)
 # just add related field two use them in the view.
 # here I chosed to give them the same name 
 # if you don't specify any attribute like string , required ....
 # they inherit the attributes of the model.one fields
 field_1 = fields.Char(related='many2one_field.field_1',
                        readonly=True)
 field_2 = fields.Date(related='many2one_field.field_2',
                        readonly=True)
```

related field work like a proxy or a compute field when you select the many2one field
there value is automatically changed.

and if you just want to fill the field with the value of the related field
create onchange event

```py
   @api.onchange('many2one_field')
   def onchange_many2OneField(self):
        # first check many2one field have value
        if self.many2one_field:
            self.field_1 = self.many2one_field.some_field_1
            self.field_2 = self.many2one_field.some_field_2
        else:
            # make them all False if it what you want
            self.field_1 = False
            self.field_2 = False
```

Comment: what if  'model.one' field_1 = fields.Many2One(..) and 
 field_2 = fields.Many2One(..)

Comment: i'm giving you an example of two model to understand the idea there is no need to write uneeded code field_1 = fields.Char(string='Label for field')

Comment: what about a field already related on model.one     cat = fields.Float(related='test_type_cat.name',)

Comment: you can make related goes to the that model 'many2one_field.test_type_cat.name' just remember to keep the same type Float here.

Comment: you have to define the same selection on the related field, too

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@api.onchange(put_your_fields_here)
def onchange_custom(self):

return {'value': {'field_1': value1, 'field_2': value_2)}
```

Comment: but how can I get values related to the first field?

Comment: `self.first_field`